# Elastigo and Go, Search Using Raw json String with variables

Tags: json, elasticsearch, go

This site have an example of elasticsearch query in go:

https://github.com/mattbaird/elastigo

The example is this:

A search using raw json string

```
searchJson := `{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}`
out, err := core.SearchRequest(true, "twitter", "tweet", searchJson, "")
if len(out.Hits.Hits) == 1 {
  fmt.Println(string(out.Hits.Hits[0].Source))
}
```

But i need something like this:

**A varible inside a raw json string**

```
term := "my search term"

searchJson := `{
        "size" : "size",
        "query" : {
            "match" : {
                "_all" : {
                    "query" : term,
                    "operator" : "and"  
                }
            }
        },
        "sort" : [{
            "name" : { 
                "order" : "asc", 
                "mode" : "avg" 
            }
        }]
    }`
```

How can i put a varible **term** inside a raw json string?

Is posible put a varible inside a raw json string?

Comment: Why you are not appending the query term when you are unmarshaling?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [templates](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template) to fill in that value:

```
term := "\"my search term\""

searchJSONTmpl := `{
        "size" : "size",
        "query" : {
            "match" : {
                "_all" : {
                    "query" : {{.Term}},
                    "operator" : "and"  
                }
            }
        },
        "sort" : [{
            "name" : { 
                "order" : "asc", 
                "mode" : "avg" 
            }
        }]
    }`

tmpl, err := template.New("blah").Parse(searchJSONTmpl)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}   

data := map[string]string{
    "Term": term,
}   

if err := tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, data); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

If you want to store the new JSON string into a variable, use [`bytes.Buffer`](https://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer) instead of `os.Stdout` when executing the template.